# Deduction Theorem: only works with closed formulas?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

On wikipedia at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization,

under **Example of a proof**, it is stated:

> The Deduction theorem was applicable in steps [...] because the
>   formulas being moved have *no free variables*.

I wasn't aware that this was a necessary assumption? It wasn't put to me that way in university; the version I had learnt was:

> Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a first order language. Assume $\Sigma$ is a set of $\mathcal{L}$-formulas. Assume $X$ and $Y$ are $\mathcal{L}$-formulas. If $\Sigma \ \cup \{X\} \vdash Y$ then $\Sigma \vdash X \rightarrow Y$.

So, when it was put to me, there wasn't any stipulation that $X$ (or $Y$) must be closed.
Wouldn't the theorem work fine if there were free variables?

Comment: The restriction is not that the formula _must be closed_ but merely that _if_ it has free variables, _then_ those free variables must not have been subject to the universal generalization rule in the proof of $\Sigma, X\vdash Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 common ways unquantified variables are meant to be interpreted in logic.  The first way, which I'll call the dependency interpretation, is that $x > 7 \vdash x > 6$ is meant to be interpreted as

$$\forall x ~(x > 7 \vdash x > 6)$$

The $x$ represents the same variable in both statements, so it is showing a variable dependency.  This is the intended interpretation for natural deduction and similar logics.  The second way, which I'll call the tautology interpretation, is that $x > 7 \vdash x > 6$ is meant to be interpreted as

$$(\forall x~x  > 7) \vdash (\forall x~x > 6)$$

This is the case for quantifier free logics like PRA, and more decisively it is the case for [Hilbert's logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quantification/#AxiForPurQuaLog).  These are logics wherein every asserted statement is meant to be a tautology.  Whether you are working in one interpretation or the other depends on your rules of inference.  If you are in a dependency interpretation, then there is no such restriction on the deduction theorem.  If you are in a tautology in interpretation, then the restriction on the deduction theorem is necessary.

In a Hilbert's logic, you can prove something like $x = 1 \vdash x = 2$ :

$$\begin{array} {rl}
x = 1 \\
\forall x,~ x = 1 & \forall3\\
(\forall x, x = 1) \to (2 = 1) & \forall1\\
2 = 1 & \text{Modus Ponens} \\
1 = 2 & \text{a=b is b=a rule} \\
x = 2 & \text{transitivity of =}
\end{array}$$

This is fine because the interpretation $(\forall x ~x=1) \vdash (\forall x~x=2)$ is vaccuously true.  But the claim $\vdash x=1 \to x=2$ isn't true at all in a sound tautology only logic.  So the restriction on the deduction theorem is necessary.

In the wikipedia link, they seem to be working in a tautology only logic: notice this similarities to the justifications given and the linked Hilbert axioms.  In step 8, they apply universal generalization without any consideration for whether the variable $y$ is present in assumptions.  This absense of a restriction on ugen is what suggests they are using a tautology only logic, which is what imposes the restriction on the deduction theorem.

Comment: There's actually a more common term for tautology only logics, but I can't remember what it is.  If someone else does, please mention it.

Comment: "a common term for tautology only logic": do you mean [propositional calculus](http://www.iep.utm.edu/prop-log/) ?

Comment: Propositional logic has that property, but so do other logics like those I mentioned in the post.