# Difference between $\vdash A\to B$ and $A\vdash B$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Is $\vdash A\to B$ equivalent to $A\vdash B$, in the sense that if you can prove one, then you can prove the other? I would prove the first by taking $A$ as a hypothesis, and then proving $B$. This would yield $A\to B$ with the introduction rule for $\to$. And for the latter I would take $A$ as a premise, and then show $B$.

So my question is: is there an important difference between the two?

Comment: I see the difference as a consequence of a Fitch-style subproof. That is, within the context of a subproof, having proved given premise $A$ that $B$ follows, you can then take that out of the subproof as $A \rightarrow B$. Effectively they are identical, but you can use one as a step to get to the other.

Comment: You will probably find all you want to know here: [Deduction theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem).

Comment: There is a common kind of logic wherein they are sometimes different which I cover here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2549961/97045 .  In short, in that kind of logic, $x > 3 \vdash x > 4$ is not the same as $\vdash x > 3 \to x > 4$ because it is meant to be interpreted as $(\forall x. x > 3) \vdash (\forall x.x > 4)$ (vacuously true) but $\vdash (\forall x. x > 3 \to x > 4)$ is false by counter example $x=4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You right that -- in any halfway sensible logic -- it is the case that $\vdash A\to B$ holds if and only if $A\vdash B$ does.

Both forms exist because they are good for different things in the structure of a proof. The form $A\vdash B$ gives you the possibility of applying further rules that depend on the internal structure of $B$ (or, depending on the system, possibly also $A$). These rules would not be able to "see behind" the $\to$ in the $\vdash A\to B$ form.

On the other hand, $\vdash A\to B$ is what you need if you're matching up with a rule that treats $A\to B$ as a unit. For example, if you want to prove $(A\to B)\land(C\to D)$ you would first need to establish $\vdash A\to B$ and $\vdash C\to D$, and then apply a $\land$ rule. The $\land$ rule knows nothing about $\to$ and wouldn't be able to invent a $\to$ from the $A\vdash B$ form by itself.

The form that's what you need for *proving* something is not always the same as the form you need when using it, so it is necessary to be able to pass from one to the other and vice versa. Fortunately this is pretty easy in *most* proof systems. (The major exception is Hilbert-style systems where it may take a major rewriting of the derivation of $A\vdash B$ to derive $\vdash A\to B$).

Comment: Just a short question related to the Deduction Theorem. Is the Deduction Theorem for Hilbert-style system of First Order Predicate Calculus a meta theorem or a meta-meta-theorem?

Comment: @user170039: I think you should ask that as a new question. Be sure to explain how you distinguish between meta and meta-meta, and why this distinction is important to you.

Comment: [Done](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2822733/is-the-deduction-theorem-a-metametatheorem-or-a-metatheorem).

Answer (score 4):

They usually are, but the details depend on what logical system you are working with.

For instance, if you have the inference rule modus ponens, then it follows that $\vdash A\to B$ implies $A\vdash B,$ since you take $A$ as an assumption, prove $A\to B$ and then use modus ponens to conclude $B.$ In a natural deduction framework, this is just the elimination rule for $\to.$

On the other hand, the fact that $A\vdash B$ implies $\vdash A\to B$ is usually proved as a theorem and called the [deduction theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem) in the study of Hilbert Style systems (e.g. in Mendelson). In a natural deduction system, it would typically just be an introduction rule for $\to.$

The equivalence is contingent on your formal system having the above features, but most systems of practical import do.

Comment: thanks for the answer! couldn't accept 2, so upvoted instead!