# Is the Deduction Theorem a metametatheorem or a metatheorem?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am talking about a Hilbert style system for Propositional Calculus. The only axioms and rule of inference that I can use are,

$\color{crimson}{\text{Axiom 1.}}\  P\to (Q\to P)$

$\color{crimson}{\text{Axiom 2.}}\  (S\to (P\to Q))\to((S\to P)\to (S\to Q))$

$\color{crimson}{\text{Axiom 3.}}\  (\neg Q\to\neg P)\to(P\to Q)$

$\color{crimson}{\text{Rule of Inference.}}$ [Modus Ponens](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj8i9j2vZHPAhVLn5QKHVpiC0YQFggmMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FModus_ponens&usg=AFQjCNGjiX3Tbw5h49jNotuefUM9xvBIDw).

My main question is regarding the Deduction Theorem for this system. Before stating my question, let me first state the Deduction Theorem for the sake of completeness of this post.

> **Deduction Theorem.** Let $\Delta$ be a set of formulas. If $\Delta\cup\{S\}\vdash T$ then $\Delta\vdash S\to T$.

Here symbols have usual meaning (if clarification is needed then please let me know via comment(s)).

The main question I have is,

> Is the Deduction Theorem a meta-theorem or a meta-meta theorem?

Due to the occurrence of $\vdash$ in the statement of Deduction Theorem and since $\vdash$ is not in the alphabet of Propositional Calculus (for example, see [here](http://assets.press.princeton.edu/chapters/s10168.pdf)) the statement for Deduction Theorem can't be a statement of the object language. In logic text books (at least the ones I have seen) the theorem is characterized as a metatheorem.

However, from the statement of the theorem it seems to me that the theorem is talking (roughly) about a property of $\vdash$. Since the theorem talks **about** a property of $\vdash$, I thought that the Deduction theorem is probably a metametatheorem. My questions are,

> 1. Is the Deduction Theorem a metametatheorem?
> 2. In which language is the proof of the Deduction Theorem being carried out (i.e., in the metalanguage or in the metametalanguage)?
> 3. Is it possible to state an prove the deduction theorem in a language which is not a Natural Language (like English)?

---

**Edit:** See [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2822733/is-the-deduction-theorem-a-metametatheorem-or-a-metatheorem#comment5821401_2822751) for further clarification of the motivation for asking this question.

Comment: See [Deduction theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem) : "In mathematical logic, the deduction theorem is a metatheorem of propositional and first-order logic. It is a formalization of the common proof technique in which an implication A → B is proved by assuming A and then deriving B from this assumption conjoined with known results. The deduction theorem explains why proofs of conditional sentences in mathematics are logically correct."

Comment: Compare with [Sequent calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus#Sequent_calculus_systems) where $\vdash$ is part of the language.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: First of all thank you very much for the reference on Sequent Calculus. I wasn't aware of the existence of it. Regarding your first comment, I already read the Wikipedia article on Deduction Theorem that you linked above.

Comment: But my question still remained because (1) in that article there was no explanation for the reason of calling it a metatheorem and (2) I took the Deduction theorem to be stating a **property** about $\vdash$, i.e., roughly speaking, one can 'switch' $P$ from the LHS of $\vdash$ to the RHS of $\vdash$. This seemed to me to require the existence of the metametalanguage. Hence my questions.

Comment: We have a mathematical object : *propositional calculus* (axioms, rules, derivations - compare with *real numbers*)) and we have a theory studying the properties of that "object" : *propositional logic* (compare with *real analysis*). Unfortunately, we are used to call the end-formula of a derivation in the calculus : a *theorem*. Thus, the result proved by usually math reasoning in the theory (*prop logic*) about the math object (*prop calculus*) are called : *meta-theorems*. End of the story.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: What is the definition of a mathematical object and how **exactly** do we characterize propositional calculus as a mathematical object? (Note that I have already gone through [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_object)).

Comment: Also please see my edit @MauroALLEGRANZA.

Comment: *Prop calculus* is a *formal system* based on a [formal language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_system) i.e. a *set* of strings of symbols. Sets a mathematical objects.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: Is involving the notion of set while describing the language *absolutely* necessary?

Comment: Mathematical logic (or any mathematical analysis of formal languages) cannot start without some way of talking about the sequences of symbols that constitute the statements in the formal language.

Comment: @RobArthan: Sure and using the notion of sets we can very conveniently talk about the sequences of symbols that constitute the statements in the formal language. But should that 'talk' *necessarily* be done using sets?

Comment: Please also see the discussion that we (me and @DougSpoonwood) have done in [this room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45211446#45211446).

Answer (score 2):

The symbol $\vdash$ is being used in your statement of the deduction as a shorthand notation; $\Delta \vdash A$ means "the formula $A$ is derivable from the set of formulas $\Delta$". The statement does not talk about $\vdash$, it just uses it.
So the deduction theorem is a metatheorem rather than a metametathorem and its proof is (in typical textbooks) carried out in a metalanguage comprising a mixture of natural language and symbols like $\vdash$, $\cup$, $\{$ and $\}$ etc.

It would be possible to state and prove the deduction theorem in a formal language like the language of set theory or in the language of a typical automated [proof assistant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_assistant).

Comment: It is true that " $\Delta \vdash A$ means "the formula $A$ is derivable from the set of formulas $\Delta$". But I took the Deduction theorem to be stating a property **about** $\vdash$ in the following rough sense: one can 'switch' $P$ from the LHS of $\vdash$ to the RHS of $\vdash$. This seemed to me to require the existence of the metametalanguage.

Comment: @user170039 As Rob says, there's no talk about $\vdash$ in the statement of it.  So, I don't see how the statement of The Deduction Theorem, when a theorem, ends up in the metametalanguage.  Now, *the proof* of the Deduction Theorem, that seems like it usually happens in the metametalanguage.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood: From the point of view provided in the answer, I agree that the statement of DT doesn't talk about $\vdash$ but just uses it. However, I was trying to read the DT *as a theorem* in the following manner: $${\color{red}{\vdash}}\Delta\cup\{P\}\vdash Q\implies \Delta\vdash P\to Q$$ where ${\color{red}{\vdash}}$ was assumed to be signify "the formula $\Delta\cup\{P\}\vdash Q\implies \Delta\vdash P\to Q$ is a theorem", in an analogous way of reading $\vdash P\to P$, say.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement of The Deduction Theorem is a bit imprecise.  It doesn't actually say, parenthesizing the implication as needed, that "Let Δ be a set of formulas. If Δ∪{S}⊢T then Δ⊢(S→T)."  If it did, then for all uses of $\vdash$ we would have that.  But, there exist some logical systems where that doesn't hold, such as Lukasiewicz's three-valued logic.  It sometimes isn't even stated in classical logic, such as in Frege's work or gets relegated to an appendix such as in Arthur Prior's book *Formal Logic*.  The Deduction Theorem as you used it says:

"Let Δ be a set of formulas. If Δ∪{S} ⊢$_{(1, 2, 3)}$ T then Δ ⊢$_{(1, 2, 3)}$ (S→T)."

So, I don't think that The Deduction Theorem talks about a property of $\vdash$.  It talks about a property of the deductive system at hand.  The "if-then" statement is the property.  That implies The Deduction Theorem as a meta-theorem of that deductive system.

Comment: In any case, I was only claiming that DT **in the context of my question** was intended to be interpreted as I have done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2822733/is-the-deduction-theorem-a-metametatheorem-or-a-metatheorem/2823701#comment5821401_2822751).

Comment: @user170039 Alright, what is the axiomatic and rule basis for your use of the red $\vdash$?  If you don't have such, I'm not sure that (((Δ∪{P})⊢Q)⟹(Δ⊢(P→Q))) is a theorem, even if semantically it makes sense.

Comment: If you don't mind then can we continue this discussion in [this room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72901/general-chat-with-user-170039)?